# WP-Commerce change variations from selects to inputs?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, e-commerce

Am currently trying to get the size variations for an e-commerce site to look like

http://www.culturekings.com.au/shoppingcart/products/Music-Merch-Inc-%252d-Nwa-Tank-%252d-Black.html

I am using WP Commerce and by default the size variations go into select fields

```
                            <select class="wpsc_select_variation" name="variation[<?php echo wpsc_vargrp_id(); ?>]" id="<?php echo wpsc_vargrp_form_id(); ?>">
                            <?php while (wpsc_have_variations()) : wpsc_the_variation(); ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo wpsc_the_variation_id(); ?>" <?php echo wpsc_the_variation_out_of_stock(); ?>><?php echo wpsc_the_variation_name(); ?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </select>
```

I tried to take them out of the option fields but It does not seem to work properly, how can I do this without breaking the e-commerce functionality?

I tried to change it to this

```
                                <label>
                                <input class="sizeBtn" type="radio" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_variation_id(); ?>" name="<?php echo wpsc_the_variation_name(); ?>">
                                <?php echo wpsc_the_variation_name(); ?>
                                <?php //echo wpsc_the_variation_out_of_stock(); ?>
                                </label>
```

The website is http://ownc.co.nz/shop/t-shirts/simply-dope/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you try like so:

```
<?php while (wpsc_have_variations()) : wpsc_the_variation();
    if ( 0 == wpsc_the_variation_id() ) { // That is usually a label and not an actual variation
        continue;
    } ?>
    <label>
        <input class="sizeBtn" type="radio" value="<?php echo wpsc_the_variation_id(); ?>" name="variation[<?php echo wpsc_vargrp_id(); ?>]" <?php echo wpsc_the_variation_out_of_stock(); ?> />
        <?php echo wpsc_the_variation_name(); ?>
    </label>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I guess you were doing the loop, but you just skipped it in your second code snippet, so the only thing that seems incorrect was the name for the inputs.

Please try this code, remove the original code(the one that generates the select) and try again.

Comment: thanks that worked really well except that it now displays "size" as a button and "please select is still there.

any idea where I would look to remove these? sorry my php is not very good

Comment: I edited the code in my answer. Now it will skip the radio button if the variation ID is 0(which should usually indicate that this is just a placeholder text like the "please select"). Actually "size" is a label and "please select" was a button, so I think this should work for you now. If you still want to remove "size" look for `<td class="col1"><label>...` - this is where the "size" label should be.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you :) Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted, so that your question won't be in the unanswered section any more.

Comment: What about the wpsc_the_variation_out_of_stock() function? In this case even out of stock variation options would be selectable, wouldn't they?

Comment: I've added the call to `wpsc_the_variation_out_of_stock()` - this should add `disabled="disabled"` if the variation is out of stock - this way you won't be able to select this variation :)